# List<> ends up being null; can't seem to .Add properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, addition

I have a `GridView` with `CheckBoxes` and I wish to retrieve `Cell[1]` in every row that was checked. The list always end up being `'null'`. The code is below. I added a string to display the output and that works fine. So I'm probably Adding it incorrectly but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers~

```
List<int> indices = new List<int>();
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

string text = "";
foreach (GridViewRow row in GV0.Rows)
{
    if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked)
    {
        text += row.Cells[1].Text;
        indices.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text));
    }
}
Label1.Text = text;
Session["indicesList"] = indices;
Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
```

The code for the page that is being redirected to:

```
        List<List<string>> all = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> fields = new List<string>();
        List<Type> fieldtypes = new List<Type>();
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        int show = 0;

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            all = (List<List<string>>)Session["all"];
            fields = (List<string>)Session["fields"];
            fieldtypes = (List<Type>)Session["fieldtypes"];
            indices = (List<int>)Session["indiceslist"];
            show = (int)Session["show"];
        }

        int j = 0;
        List<List<string>> dupes = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < show; i++)
        {
            if (j < indices.Count)
            {
                if (int.Parse(all[i][0]) == indices[j])
                {
                    dupes.Add(all[i]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: *Where* does the list end up being null? In the code you've given, it certainly won't be.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say that the list ends up empty? In the code you showed, the list won't ever be null.

Comment: Have you set the GridView canuseraddrows to true?

Comment: @JonSkeet In the page that I redirect to, when I retrieve the session object and run a loop with it's Count, it gives me the NullReferenceException implying that my list is null. But during debug it also says that the original List<> is also null on the original page. So my guess is that the error most likely arose from the code I posted above.

Comment: Are you checking the IsPostBack?

Comment: @JackeryXu: Right, so it's not propagating to the *session*. That wasn't made at all clear in the question. So now you should show us the code that's fetching it from the session and using it. (For example, if you've got a typo in the name when you fetch, that would explain it very simply.)

Comment: Surprisingly, that was the exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting your list in the session with a key of `indicesList` but you're retrieving it with a key of `indiceslist` (Note the difference in case on the letter "L").

I would suggest creating a property for your list that gets and sets from the session. It makes it much easier to manage.

```
public List<int> Indices
{
    get
    {
        var val = Session["indicesList"] as List<int>;
        if(val == null) 
        {
            val = new List<int>();
            Session["indicesList"] = val;
        }
        return val;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["indicesList"] = value;
    }
}
```